# How to change color of navigation bar in mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller while presenting it in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

```
        MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
        [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:254.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        [[messageController navigationBar] setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [messageController setBody:message];
        [messageController navigationBar].translucent =NO;                                             
        [messageController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:127.0f/255.0f blue:254.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
        // Present message view controller on screen
        [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:^{
        [messageController navigationBar].translucent = NO;
        }];
```

I have been using this code. Please let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: Please edit your post to make the code readable.  Hint: indent each line by 4 spaces to form a code block.

Comment: Try moving the line which sets the tintColor to the completion handler of the presentation.

Comment: no change it is still coming white.

Comment: @Bhumica It is updating the navigation bar color and navigation bar text color on every other screen except MFMessageComposeViewController.

Comment: You have to call this method  where you have called MFMessageComposeViewController not everywhere. In my code its working fine.

Comment: I have called this method right before initializing  MFMessageComposeViewController and it has changed all the navigation bar colors throughout the app except in MFMessageComposeViewController.

Comment: Where you are calling your  MFMessageComposeViewController ?on viewdidload?

Comment: No in actionsheet delegate method. Strangely it is changing the text color everytime I change navigation tintcolor but not changing bartintcolor in any case so far.

Comment: go through you code in detail.You are doing something wrong.Its working in my app completely.

Comment: I am only using MFMessageComposeViewController here no where else. I am also very astonished that why it is not working. Despite it is changing the tintcolor but not bartint color.

Comment: write your whole code here.

Comment: This is the whole code.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add two lines to change navigation bar color.

**For  MFMailComposeViewController.**

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[mc.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];//cancel button will be of white color.
[mc.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];//bar color will be black.

if (mc != nil)
        {
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
            [mc setMessageBody:bodyText isHTML:YES];
            [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

            [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
```

**For MFMessageComposeViewController**

Create one method like below for changing navigation bar color.

```
- (void)setNavBarColor:(UIColor *)navBarColor titleColor:(UIColor *)titleColor {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:navBarColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:17.0f],
                                                          UITextAttributeFont,
                                                          titleColor,
                                                          UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                          nil]];
}
```

And write this method before  you initialise `MFMessageComposeViewController`.**(This is very important otherwise it will not work)**

This code work for me in ios 9.

May be it will help you.

Comment: no the black color or any other color is not appearing in navigation bar. Tried this too.

Comment: I am using mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller. Tried in that.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, either, with MFMessageComposeViewController.

Comment: Verified that it *does* work for MFMailComposeViewController.  Wonder why their implementations are so different as to make this code only work for one.

Comment: It is not working for MFMailComposeViewController for me.

Comment: MfMessageCompose... works properly. Do not forget as mentioned above :- "And write this method before you initialize MFMessageComposeViewController.(This is very important otherwise it will not work)".

Answer (score 0):

I tried the edit with the solution mentioned up above and it didn't quite work. However, I found a solution with some help. My solution worked with a build target of iOS12.1+ and I tested it on iOS15.4:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];
[messageController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];
[self presentViewController:messageController animated:true completion:nil];
[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[MFMessageComposeViewController class]]].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

[MFMessageComposeViewController: Cannot Style "Cancel" Button in Dark Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776903/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-cannot-style-cancel-button-in-dark-mode)